# Assigning to value (rvalue ?) returned by function doesn't give compile error

Tags: c++

In the code below, why doesn't the assignment to get_string_val() give compilation error ? It looks like the function is returning an rvalue.

Of course, this is a simple example and this could be a member function returning a member variable. This can cause a bad bug if I had intended to return std::string& but mis-typed and returned std::string.

It looks like "xxx" is getting assigned to a temporary variable returned by get_string_val() ?

```
std::string get_string_val()
{
    std::string x;
    return x;
}

int main()
{

    get_string_val() = "xxx";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `std::string` has an overloaded (custom) assignment operator. This operator can be invoked for `rvalue std::string`, as long as the object is not const-qualified.

You'd have a compilation error if your `get_string` would return `const std::string`.

By the way, things work differently for built-in types, which do not have `operator=` overloaded for them. `int get_int(); get_int() = 25;` would be a compilation error.

Comment: I will like to add that this works even with default assignment operator (not just overloaded). Following compiles : `class A {
    public:
        int i;
};

A get_A() {

    A a;
    return a;
}

main()
{

    A d1;
    get_A() = d1;
}`